# Name that Connector -- 2 conductor crimp-on parallel

Tags: connector, identification

I need to source a type of connector. Don't know the correct name, though, so searching DigiKey is an exercise in frustration.  The connectors are 2 conductor, female, 0.1" spacing. They are designed to crimp down onto the middle of a length of two-conductor 24awg wire (ie, "zip wire") and have a 2-pin 0.1" male header inserted. They act like IDC, but only 2-conductor -- you end up with multiple "taps" in parallel off the trunk line.  Any idea what this connector style is called?

(Bonus points if you can suggest a source in west LA that's open weekends; slightly fewer bonus points if you can suggest a source that does overnight shipping).

Comment: Photo of the connector or the mating connector may help.

Comment: sounds like a scotchlock connector

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is the AMP or [TE Connectivity MTA-100](http://www.te.com/catalog/minf/en/692) family of connectors. These are available for various wire gauges (22-28) and are available as closed-end or feed-through.

[image: MTA-100 Closed End]
[image: MTA-100 Feed Through]
*Closed-end on left, feed-through at right.*

In my experience, 24 gauge wire is generally not what I would consider "zip" wire, but can be found with a common insulation like on a ribbon cable. The MTA connectors require that the conductors of the wire be separated as there is a plastic tab between the IDC connectors that interface with it. For ribbon cable, I split the conductors apart when needed as shown above. There is also the option of a ribbon cable notching, which TE shows in the [product datasheet](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data+Sheet%7F82056_MTA%7F0608%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_82056_MTA_0608.pdf):

[image: Notched Ribbon Cable]

These mate with male pin headers 0.1" center to center.

Since you specified that what you are looking for is 2-conductor female, I don't think Scotchlok connector is what you want. Those are basically a wire tap:

[image: Scotchlok tap]

Back to the MTA-100 connectors: The ones in my pictures are green, which are for 28 gauge wire. The ones for 24 gauge are white. Without polarity tabs, the part numbers are:

- Feed through: [3-640621-2](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/3-640621-2/A31002-ND/698250)
- Closed end: [3-640441-2](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&site=us&keywords=3-640441-2&x=0&y=0)

You will probably also want to pick up the manual ["T-Handle" maintenance (insertion) tool (59803-1)](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&site=us&keywords=59803-1&x=0&y=0):

[image: T-handle maintenance tool]